# How should I sanitize database input in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, security, sql-injection

Could someone please point me to a good beginner guide on safely running SQL queries formed partly from user input?  I'm using Java, but a language neutral guide is fine too.

The desired behaviour is that if someone types into the GUI something like

`very nice;) DROP TABLE FOO;`

The database should treat it as a literal string and store it safely without dropping any tables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You definitely want to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)s. They are convenient.  Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementAddBatchMySQL.htm).

Answer (score 7):

Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

Answer (score 5):

Normally, you shouldn't create a query concatenating input, but using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

That lets you specify in which places you'll be setting your parameters inside your query, so Java will take care of sanitizing all inputs for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your user input would actually have to be `"Bob'; delete from foo; select '"` (or something like that) so the implicit quotes added by the prepared statement would be closed:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE NAME = 'Bob'; delete from foo; select ''
```

but if you do that the prepared statement code will quote your quote so you get an actual query of

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE NAME = 'Bob''; delete from foo; select '''
```

and your name would be stored as `"Bob', delete from foo; select '"` instead of running multiple queries.

Answer (score 3):

PreparedStatement?  Yes, absolutely.  But I think there's one more step: validation of input from UI and binding to objects prior to getting close to the database.

I can see where binding a String in PreparedStatement might still leave you vulnerable to a SQL injection attack:

```
String userInput = "Bob; DELETE FROM FOO";
String query = "SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE NAME = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, userInput);
ps.executeQuery();
```

I've gotta admit that I haven't tried it myself, but if this is remotely possible I'd say PreparedStatement is necessary but not sufficient.  Validating and binding on the server side is key.

I'd recommend doing it with Spring's binding API.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of attack that prepared statements are meant to protect against.  It will escape the ;.

Comment: Technically the PreparedStatement interface does not guarantee it. Although if your driver does something different, find a new vendor.

Comment: @daniel - I'll have to try it and see for myself.  Whether I'm correct about that or not, do you not agree that server-side validation is still a good idea?

Comment: @duffymo: Of course data validation is a good idea, both for security and for application logic.  But server-side prepared statements should keep parameter values separate from the SQL syntax throughout the query execution.  They are never interpolated into the query, so no escaping is necessary.

Comment: "should" - there's the key word.

Comment: But prepared statements have inconvenience w.r.t to IN clause/ dynamically appending `AND` conditions based on availability of Input, ORDER BY clause etc, which might lead to performance drawbacks / code readability issues. Is there an alternative for that ?

Comment: None that I know of.  I doubt that your performance concerns are measurable.  This answer is 11 years old.  Ask a new question if you must.  Your comment isn't helpful.